# Separate L shape into two lines

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm looking to detect the distance and orientation from a marker. The marker is an L-shape; two lines of equal width and height connected to form an L-shape.

To detect the orientation and distance I need to dissect the L-shape caught on camera into two lines.

What is a lightweight way to do this, given the code needs to run multiple times per frame?

I have already implemented blob detection using the algorithm described here: http://www.labbookpages.co.uk/software/imgProc/blobDetection.html .

I have thought about using Hough Transform, but I fear it takes a lot of processing power to perform each frame. On top of that, I assume it is not the most accurate method for this case. I have already performed proper analysis to extract an accurate vector from a single line, but am not sure how to cut the L-shape into two lines.

Below a picture of different results of how the L-shape could be caught by the camera.

[image: Example]

I was thinking I could segment the L-shape by separating it with a line through the centroid and center of the boundingbox, but that doesn't work out.

A rough brainstorm sketch of how I think it might be done:

[image: Rough sketch]

Comment: Can you repost the same image in PNG ? I'm trying to use your sample image for my answer but JPEG compression looses some info making it difficult to have proper segmentation easily =(

Comment: Sure, coming right up!

Comment: Previous picture is now replaced with PNG.

Comment: Thanks ! Much better =)
One answer, coming up !

Comment: Curious as to what your approach will be :) I've been thinking about this for days!

Comment: What else is in the image? Can multiple `L` shapes appear in one image?

Comment: I've edited the question a bit. I already applied blob detection and already know if a blob is to be analysed or not. Hough Transform is less accurate than possible, and is probably slow too to perform each frame.

Comment: Hough can be memory intensive without requiring too many processing cycles--there are ways of implementing Hough that can be quite fast. What is the image size? How much memory do you have available for image processing? Will the thickness of the line segments be nearly constant (N +/-1 pixels) in every image? If so, what is that thickness? Could you post a real image as captured by the camera? When the L-shapes are dissected (split into two line segments), what should the resulting image look like? I can think of several relatively simple approaches, but the best fit depends on your specs.

Comment: @Kaj_Toet See my updated answer for an intriguing new insight =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Scanlines !

**See the (updated) walkthrough [here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/OverkillGuy/c650249047b493ba8c0f) in Python**, with images to visualize my journey through your data :)

Skip to the end for the "Scanlines" solution

[image: Lines]
[image: Vectors]

---

### Scanlines

## Basics

#### Assumptions

I assume these constraints from your sample image

- You have (several) L-shapes in your image.
- You can easily segment them (no overlapping shapes, no continuation of one L into another ...)
- You know the exact width of line strokes in your Ls

#### Label your binary image

You want to know first which pixels are part of which L, which is done by "labeling" the binary image.

Compute also the bounding box of each volume, like so:

#### Rotating your coordinate system

The real trick now is changing from the x/y orthogonal system into a "L-Shaped referential" for each shape.

Think of it as redefining the X axis as one branch of the L, and the Y axis as the other branch.
Once we compute the transformation vectors of one into the other, we're safe !

#### Let's consider the PCA way

The problem we now face ("estimate the biggest axis of variations in dataset") is a moment where eigenvectors of covariance can be used.

I won't get into it too deeply, but you can look at this [intro to PCA](http://www.lauradhamilton.com/introduction-to-principal-component-analysis-pca) posting to get the feel of it.

The problem is usually defined in higher dimensions ("given a 50 dimensional dataset, compute the 10-biggest axes of variation in it"), but can be stretched to your 2D point-cloud problem by considering each shape individually and stating that every pixel belonging to the L is a point in your 2D space.

It would be a waste of computing power though, because compared to the usual case of PCA, you already have constraints on your L-points location (they're on a line, not randomly scattered). The beast of linear algebra that this problem involves is overkill on this small problem

#### Hough Lines, to the rescue !

You just want to find the lines in your 2D image ?
Use the Hough transform for lines (also called "hough lines").
OpenCV has it.

Again a nice intro : [OpenCV's python tutorial on Hough Lines](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghlines/py_houghlines.html)

I used the skeleton of your binary image (so that each line is upvoted only once), and chose manually the parameters I give to OpenCV for the algorithm.
This is the reason that the lines sometimes don't seem to match exactly the specific image, it's because of the sampling rate and such =)

---

## A New Hope

After you pointed out the need for computational speed, I thought of some more techniques using properties of your image to your advantage.

#### RANSAC

I thought of using a RANSAC variant over your data : after all, you want to fit lines into your point cloud.
The basic technique is as you probably know summed up with

- (randomly) pick enough data to fit a model (line in your case)
- evaluate the number of outliers (data points for which the model doesn't work)
- reiterate and keep a tally of the highest-scoring model (and keep doing that a certain number of time, involving math)

A great intro to RANSAC is [this song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1YNjMxxXO-E) (oddly enough)

But I see complications :

- **Which Model?** : do you use 4 points to define 2 lines, or do you do 2 points for a line and do it twice ?
- **No outliers** : You don't really have proper outliers, so why use RANSAC over such a trivial problem ?
- **Computing power** : You would really iterate potentially thousands of times for no reason because you're looking randomly through your points.

**Needless to say, RANSAC can't just do the trick, but we can use it as inspiration**

### Scanlines !

Let's consider your Ls' bounding boxes.

If we slice it horizontally at `Y=0`, we will have a 1D array with a contiguous area defined to `True`

So what if we slice through the image like this at intervals to define the L's vectors ?

**Setting a 5 percentile as baseline, we just find "which X-index is the center of the 1D array of Y=0 values", then do the same of `Y = 0.05 * img_width`.**

We now have 2 2D points defining the first line through your image.

Repeat on the other side and you have your solution !

Computationally, you are simply finding 4 medians in `img_width` length arrays,
each of which is a contiguous chunk of memory from your image (Heeeeelllo L2-cache hits !).

Again, if it's a bit hard to imagine just now, see the end part of my [code walkthrough](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/OverkillGuy/c650249047b493ba8c0f)

Comment: Although I had considered Hough Transform, I think there is a faster and more accurate method possible. Given the code needs to run every frame (on a low end device) it is important the calculation is as fast as possible. Also since I do triangulation I need the maximum accuracy. As your solution shows the sampling rate needs to be low for fast processing.

Comment: True enough. I remember a paper avoiding differential to estimate orientation, see it there : http://www.vsi.cs.uni-frankfurt.de/download/EUSIPCO2000.pdf
Note that with the performance constraint, your question becomes deep wizardry ! (Research papers and such)

Comment: See my updated solution, using Scanlines-derived technique.
I actually woke up in the middle of the night to write this idea down ^^

Comment: I had a similar idea yesterday evening coincidentally :) I think it is close to your approach, but a bit faster. I'm still working on it, if it doesn't work out I'll try your way for sure.

Comment: You know what they say about great minds ... ;)
You are right in that there is a ton of optimization to be done in my method though.

Comment: I added a new approach I am trying, which almost works and is quite fast. It would be great if you know some adjustments to it to improve it! :) It's still kind of rough..